# PHP variable not updating when $_GET exists

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable that I am trying to be able to update by means of a $_GET request, but the first time the page is loaded, it isn't updated. After the initial page load, if I reload the page again, it is updated. Why won't it work the first time?

PAGE.PHP:

```
$name = 'Bob';

include('start.php');

echo $name;
```

START.PHP:

```
if isset($_GET['name']) {
  $name = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Example: page.php?name=Mary

Comment: does it shows any errors?

Comment: provide us more information. What is the current output ?

Comment: @holpducki No. It's just the first time the page is visited, it will display "Bob". If I refresh the page, it will then show "Mary", but only after a refresh.

Comment: At least through 5.6.9, `START.PHP` won't compile.  I strongly suspect caching is at play, since the PHP in start isn't running.

Comment: If you are to continue developing in PHP please turn on error reporting to make troubleshooting easier. Add this to the top of you scripts: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start file has a syntax error, therefore the code never gets executed.

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
   ^--------------------^--- missing
```

e.g.:

```
php > if isset($foo) { echo 'foo'; }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'isset' (T_ISSET), expecting '(' in php shell code on line 1
php > if (isset($foo)) { echo 'foo'; }
php >
```

Comment: But why it gets executed the second time OP reloads the page?